# c# convert byte to string and write to txt file

Tags: c#, string, byte

How can i convert for example `byte[] b = new byte[1]; b[1]=255` to string ?
I need a string variable with the value "255" `string text= "255";`and then store it in a text file?

Comment: Admits to confusion.....

Comment: What's stored in that array? characters?

Answer (score 15, accepted):

Starting from bytes:

```
        byte[] b = new byte[255];
        string s = Encoding.UTF8.GetString(b);
        File.WriteAllText("myFile.txt", s);
```

and if you start from string:

```
        string x = "255";
        byte[] y = Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes(x);
        File.WriteAllBytes("myFile2.txt", y);
```

Comment: That will not produce the string `"255"`, it will return the UTF8 character which the byte value `255` represents.

Comment: As @Dave wrote question is not clear. So my point was to show OP how to convert between bytes and string and write result to file. I am sure this is all he needs in this case.

Comment: no i am sorry i didn't mean that. I need a byte b=255; to produce a string text="255";

Comment: Well this is not a problem if you want just that: byte bValue = 255; string sValue = bValue.ToString();

Comment: And what if bValue is an array? byte bValue[]
I guess bValue[k].ToString();

Comment: This is also no problem. Just use specific index, here is sample: byte[] bValue = new byte[] { 255 }; string sValue = bValue[0].ToString();

Answer (score 3):

No need to convert to string.  You can just use [File.WriteAllBytes](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.io.file.writeallbytes.aspx)

```
File.WriteAllBytes(@"c:\folder\file.txt", byteArray);
```

Comment: But what if I wanted a string before writing the txt file?